# Cant connect into neo4j web pannel via docker container launched with docker-compose

Tags: docker, neo4j, docker-compose

Over my `docker-compose.yml` I have inserted the following entries:

```
version: '2'
services:
neo4j_dev:
    image: 'neo4j'
    ports:
      - '7474:7474'
      - '7687:7487'
    volumes:
      - './docker-volumes/neo4j_dev/data:/data'
    environment:
      NEO4J_AUTH: 'neo4j/somepasswdthatisnotmyrealpassword'
```

Now when I visit over my browser http://0.0.0.0:7474/browser/ but somehow when I enter the following credentials it fails to login:

- host: bolt://localhost:7687
- user: neo4j
- password: somepasswdthatisnotmyrealpassword

But it fails to login with an error response:

> ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers developm.

Do you know what's wrong with the settings and I cannot login?

Comment: is this how your docker compose file is really `7687:7487`? or is it a typo?

Comment: Yes this is how I setup my `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `7687:7687`?

Comment: Yeap that was the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the wrong port as mentions over: https://hub.docker.com/_/neo4j/ the neo4j listens over these ports:

- 7474
- 7687

The latter one is mismapped over your docker compose. Instead of `7687:7487` it should be `7687:7687` on both on your `docker-compose.yml`.